# SharePoint 2013 - Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a SharePoint site using stsadm.exe ( SharePoint command line administration tool ). The site has been created successfully. It can be browsed and the site administrator can log-in to the site.

BUT, every other user which was added to site using the command below

*stsadm -o adduser -url "http://test.sharepoint2013.com" -userlogin "LAB01\testuser1" -useremail "testuser@sp2013.com" -role "Full Control" -username "Test User"*

the user is added successfully into SharePoint site and the Roles/Permission Levels are also successfully assigned.

**But the user CANNOT login to the site. It says "Sorry, this site hasn’t been shared with you."**

I have verified the user has proper permission levels assigned and can be seen in site.

There is certainly no such problem in SharePoint 2010/2007.

Please guide. I ll be thankful to you!

Regards,
Rizwan

Comment: You may want to try posting your question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

"Run As Administrator" your browser, and then access the site.

After trying many other solutions, this worked for me.

For more information [SharePoint 2013 – Configure service accounts – Access Required](http://www.sharepointtrainingonline.com/sharepoint-2013-configure-service-accounts-access-required/):

> The solution is actually quite simple but unfortunately not documented well yet; I had to open and run Internet Explorer as an Administrator.